What are the units of the thermodynamic expression $PV^\gamma=\text{const}$?
Consider the expression
$$PV^\gamma=\text{const}\tag{1}$$
This is the relationship between pressure and volume during an adiabatic process for an ideal gas.
My question is about how to think about the units in this equation.
$\gamma$ is a constant that is larger than 1.
Pressure can be measured in $\text{Pa}=\mathrm{\frac{N}{m^2}}$ and so pressure times volume comes out to $\mathrm{\frac{N}{m^2}\cdot m^3=N\cdot m=J}$.
But we have pressure times volume raised to a non-integer power.
What are the units of $P\cdot V^\gamma$?
Suppose we observe a gas at $P\ \text{Pa}$ and $V\ \mathrm{m^3}$.
When we sub into (1) what happens to the units?
Do we write the following
$$\mathrm{P\ Pa\cdot (V\ \mathrm{m^3})^\gamma=P\ \text{Pa}\cdot V^\gamma\ (\mathrm{m^3})^\gamma}$$
This seems weird.
What about if we convert $V$ to liters?
Then, $V\ \mathrm{m^3}=V\cdot 10^3\ \text{L}$
$$\mathrm{P\ Pa\cdot (V\cdot 10^3\ \text{L})^\gamma}$$
$$\mathrm{=P\ Pa\cdot V^\gamma\cdot(10^3)^\gamma\ L^\gamma}$$
$$=\mathrm{P\ Pa\cdot V^\gamma\ (10^3 L)^\gamma}$$
$$=\mathrm{P\ Pa\cdot V^\gamma\ (m^3)^\gamma}$$
The following seems definitely incorrect
$$\mathrm{P\ Pa\cdot V^\gamma\ m^3}$$
$$=\mathrm{P\ Pa\cdot (V\cdot 10^3)^\gamma\ L}$$
$$=\mathrm{P\ Pa\cdot V^\gamma\cdot (10^3)^\gamma\cdot (10^{-3})\ m^3}$$
$$=\mathrm{P\ Pa\cdot V^\gamma\cdot (10^3)^{\gamma-1}\ m^3}$$
Below are some example expressions using Maple.
Note that I am using with(Units:-Simple) and that the units shown below are actual units in this package.

Maple does give a result for an expression such as $\mathrm{(m^3)^{1,67}}$. But it gives an error when we try to multiply this by $1\ \text{Pa}$.

This is an interesting problem, but I think it belongs in physics.se rather than here

Why physics? Is the use of units not rigorously defined in math rather than physics? True I am using the domain of thermodynamics to illustrate the question, which I think can make it easier to think about it maybe, but this is a general math problem, no? Such an equation as $PV^\gamma=\text{const}$ can arise in any domain.

I just added the tag "dimensional-analysis".

Ah yes, precisely the tag I was looking for but had forgotten about.

To solve your issues with units in Maple, for the case $\gamma =5/3$ simply consider the equation $$P^3 V^5= \mathrm{const.}$$ which is equivalent to the original equation.

May be, it could be better to go back to $$\int\frac{dP}P=-\gamma \int\frac{dV}V$$

@Crostul That indeed allows Maple not to show an error. But my question is conceptual. In general, how do we think about a variable with units raised to a non-integer power in a mathematical expression? Of course, since I use Maple, an answer to the conceptual question allows me to improve my understanding of how this Units:-Simple package works as well.

@ClaudeLeibovici It seems you have done $PV^\gamma=c$, then $\ln{P}=c-\gamma\ln{V}$, then you differentiate to get $\frac{1}{P}=-\gamma\frac{1}{V}$, and then you integrate both sides. How does this help to understand the units of $c$?

No, I went back to definitions

The integral $\int dp/p$ is not $\ln p$ if you want to be dimensionally correct. It is $\ln (p / p_0)$ where $p_0$ is an arbitrary constant. Mathematically, it's just an alternate form of the $+C$ thing, but it must be written this way for units. Now you just have $(p / p_0)^{1.31}$ which is a number raised to a power.

In addition, derived physical laws and empirical laws often have very weird units, so meters to the 2.42-th power isn't really that unacceptable.

There are a few attitudes to take here. One is to simply take the units as $[P][V]^\gamma$, and this is not entirely strange: if $y=x^2/(4a)$ defines the parabolic arc of a projectile, we can solve to obtain $x=\sqrt{4ay}=2a^{1/2}y^{1/2}$. It's entirely consistent to take the dimensions as $L^{1/2}$ for both terms, thus recovering $[x]=L$ as expected. Non-rational powers are perhaps less familiar but are not really any stranger. (Examples with non-rational powers are particularly ubiquitous in the context of phase transitions, where rational critical exponents are very much the exception.)
That said, it's also really not necessary. Let $P_0,V_0$ be reference values of pressure and volume. (Say, 1 pascal and 1 cubic meter---the choice is arbitrary and can be chosen for convenience.) Then $P_0 V_0^\gamma$ is fixed and cannot change, so therefore the quantity $$\frac{P V^\gamma}{P_0 V_0^\gamma}=\left(\frac{P}{P_0}\right)\left(\frac{V}{V_0}\right)^\gamma$$ is also constant in any adiabatic process. So we can just define the thermodynamic relationship in terms of dimensionless ratios, eliminating any unit issues. This is also applicable to the original differential form $$\frac{dP}{P}=\gamma \frac{dV}{V}$$ but is a bit superfluous since both sides are already dimensionless.
Alternatively, if we're only comparing two points along the adiabat we can rewrite
$$P_1 V_1^\gamma =P_2 V_2^\gamma \implies (P_2/P_1)(V_2/V_1)^\gamma=1$$
This again involves only dimensionless ratios.

In what follows I don't actually answer the original question in general.
However, I will illustrate a practical calculation that shows where the original question arises and the conclusions about the units that seem to follow.
Suppose we have
$$V_1=0.002478819100\ \mathrm{m^3}\tag{1}$$
$$V_2=0.009840450400\ \mathrm{m^3}\tag{2}$$
Then
$$V_1=2.578819100\text{L}\tag{3}$$
$$V_2=9.840450400\text{L}\tag{4}$$
Also
$$P_1=10\ \text{bar}\tag{5}$$
$$P_2=1\ \text{bar}\tag{6}$$
Then
$$\mathrm{P_1\ bar\cdot (V_1\ L)^{1.67}}=45.53956444\mathrm{\ bar\cdot L^{1.67}}=k_1\tag{7}$$
$$\mathrm{P_1\ bar\cdot (V_1\ m^3)^{1.67}=0.0004450295740\ bar\cdot (m^3)^{1.67}}=k_2\tag{8}$$
Here we see that the numerical value of the constant depends on the units used.
The constants $k_1$ and $k_2$ are just a single constant, of course, when we use the same units.
To go from (7) to (8) we do
$$k_1=45.53956444\mathrm{\ bar\cdot L^{1.67}}=45.53956444\mathrm{\ bar\cdot (10^{-3}\ m^3)^{1.67}}\tag{9}$$
$$=45.53956444\mathrm{\ bar\cdot (10^{-3})^{1.67}\ (m^3)^{1.67}}\tag{10}$$
$$=\mathrm{0.0004450295740\ bar\cdot (m^3)^{1.67}}=k_2\tag{11}$$
Consider a calculation of work.
$$w=-\int PdV\tag{12}$$
If we use $k_1$ then we must do
$$w=-\int_{V_1\ L}^{V_2\ L} \frac{k_1\ \mathrm{bar\ L^{1.67}}}{(V\ \text{L})^{1.67}}(dV\ L)\tag{13}$$
$$=-22.30823896\mathrm{\ bar\ L}\tag{14}$$
$$=-22.30823896\mathrm{\ bar\ 10^{-3} m^3}\tag{15}$$
$$=-0.02230823896\mathrm{\ bar\ m^3}\tag{16}$$
If we use $k_2$ then we must do
$$w=-\int_{V_1\ \mathrm{m^3}}^{V_2\ \mathrm{m^3}} \frac{k_2\ \mathrm{bar\ (m^3)^{1.67}}}{(V\ \mathrm{(m^3)^{1.67}}}(dV\ \mathrm{m^3})\tag{17}$$
$$=-0.02230823896\mathrm{\ bar\ m^3}\tag{18}$$
From this calculation, which is what prompted me to write the OP, seems to indicate that the units of $PV^\gamma$ are indeed
$$[P][V]^{\gamma}\tag{19}$$
these units seems weird to me, because for example $\mathrm{bar\ (m^3)^{1.67}}$ doesn't have any intuitive physical meaning for me, but these units do seem to work from a mathematical perspective.
In addition, this whole topic does seem to be of practical value since one does need to be careful with units in computing integrals such as the work integrals above.
In fact, discrepancies in my calculations are what made me ask the original question.
Now, I did the calculations above in Maple without using the Units:-Simple package because some of the calculations generate an error.
It is not clear why a calculation such as (7) isn't possible for Units:-Simple.
